# Snowflake vs Snowflake Preview App and other general clarifications in using Snowflake with Power BI

Tags: sql, powerbi, etl, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

This post might seem as if I haven't used a search engine to answer my own questions, as my questions are general and quite basic, but I assure you I have - I'm just that big of a noob where I need a little more direction / context to connect the dots.

Here are the some questions I'm confused about:

- Is the Preview App a 1:1 replacement to the standard UI?
- Why would someone use one over the other?
- In Preview, is the use case of Dashboards generally for BI purposes or ETL purposes?
- Where do worksheets fit in with dashboards?
- Can I mock up my final PBI data model for ETL/Validation through Dashboards? It would be nice to write queries or import worksheets to create the general structure of my PBI Data model, then split off the individual tables into views to connect to.
- I seem to always be above the record limit for statistics / Query Details. Is there any way to adjust this? Seems odd that my relatively small amount of data exceeds Snowflakes ability to perform basic analytics on it. (My Queries return a maximum 4-5 million records, but most of the time 100k - 2M records)
- Best practice to ensure Dimension and Fact tables are 1:*? ( I know how to write queries to check this, in something like SSMS, however I'm wondering if there are quicker, built in features to highlight this)
- What the ideal workflow looks like - from writing queries & ETL to connecting to views in PBI
- In general for a PBI Developer, what are the biggest advantages of utilizing Snowflake over something like SSMS? What are the limitations?

Clearly I don't have the fundamentals down and need to take a relatively in-depth class - for now I'm just looking to get some momentum going.

If there are any resources you would recommend, I'd love to check them out also!

Comment: Too many questions, you might want to move this conversation to https://reddit.com/r/snowflake for a longer discussion. Stack Overflow policies like having only one question per question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give you some quick answers, but this is not the best place to ask so many questions at the same time. Try https://reddit.com/r/snowflake for further conversations please.

- Is the Preview App a 1:1 replacement to the standard UI?

It's the future UI, so it should match features.

- Why would someone use one over the other?

Preference :).

- In Preview, is the use case of Dashboards generally for BI purposes or ETL purposes?

BI, I'd say.

- Where do worksheets fit in with dashboards?

One worksheet per visualization is the current idea.

- Can I mock up my final PBI data model for ETL/Validation through Dashboards? It would be nice to write queries or import worksheets to create the general structure of my PBI Data model, then split off the individual tables into views to connect to.

I will let someone else answer this. Please ask in a separate question or on reddit.

- I seem to always be above the record limit for statistics / Query Details. Is there any way to adjust this? Seems odd that my relatively small amount of data exceeds Snowflakes ability to perform basic analytics on it. (My Queries return a maximum 4-5 million records, but most of the time 100k - 2M records)

The preview app looks at the result of queries and summarizes them. 4 million rows are outside of scope for the app (not for Snowflake, but for the client side app that looks at the results)

- Best practice to ensure Dimension and Fact tables are 1:*? ( I know how to write queries to check this, in something like SSMS, however I'm wondering if there are quicker, built in features to highlight this)

I will let someone else answer this. Please ask in a separate question or on reddit.

- What the ideal workflow looks like - from writing queries & ETL to connecting to views in PBI

I will let someone else answer this. Please ask in a separate question or on reddit.

- In general for a PBI Developer, what are the biggest advantages of utilizing Snowflake over something like SSMS? What are the limitations?

I will let someone else answer this. Please ask in a separate question or on reddit.